# Bootstrap multiple carousel slider not working

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using multiple carousel slider on single page. they was working about one month ago but today when i have seen one of them working and one is not working. and there are not any error in console.
http://1stfold.com/taskbox/Farrukh/completed/Gtech-new/2015/index.html

i am using different id for both sliders.

```
<div id="carousel-c" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
<div id="carousel-a" class="carousel slide carousel-sync" data-interval="false">
```

and script is here.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.carousel-sync').carousel('cycle');
$('.carousel-sync').on('click', '.carousel-control[data-slide]', function (ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    $('.carousel-sync').carousel($(this).data('slide'));
});
$('.carousel-sync').on('mouseover', function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    $('.carousel-sync').carousel('pause');
});
$('.carousel-sync').on('mouseleave', function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    $('.carousel-sync').carousel('cycle');
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you init the carousel-c?
It doesn't have the carousel-sync class, so just wondering...

Comment: I am using something like this

Comment: but not working on my end. here is not init carousel-c

Comment: if we use carousel-sync then both slider work with same arrow icon one move left other also move